# sqlite no such table

Tags: android, database, sqlite, mobile

can anyone please help. I've seen many people with the same problem and looked at all suggestions but still cannot get this to work. I have tried to unistall the application and install again, I have tried to change the version number and start again. I've debugged the code and it does go into the onCreate function, but when I go to make a select query it says the users table does not exist. Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thanks guys

DatabaseHandler Class

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{   
    // Variables
    protected static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;            
    protected static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyUser.db";

    // Constructor
    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) 
    { 
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); 
    } 

    // Creating Tables 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {           
        // Create the Users table
        // NOTE: I have the column variables saved above
        String CREATE_USERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users("
  + KEY_PRIMARY_ID + " " + INTEGER + " " + PRIMARY_KEY + " " + AUTO_INCREMENT + " " + NOT_NULL + "," + USERS_KEY_EMAIL + " " + NVARCHAR+"(1000)" + " " + UNIQUE + " " + NOT_NULL + "," + USERS_KEY_PIN + " " + NVARCHAR+"(10)" + " " + NOT_NULL + ")"; 
  db.execSQL(CREATE_USERS_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database 
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    { 
      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Users"); 
        onCreate(db); 
    }
```

UserDataSource class

```
public class UserDataSource 
{
    private SQLiteDatabase db;  
    private DatabaseHandler dbHandler;

    public UserDataSource(Context context) 
    {
        dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    }

    public void OpenWriteable() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void Close() 
    {
        dbHandler.close();
    }

    // Validate the user login with the username and password provided
    public void ValidateLogin(String username, String pin) throws CustomException
    {   
         Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(   "select * from Users where " + DatabaseHandler.USERS_KEY_EMAIL + " = '" + username + "'" + " and " + DatabaseHandler.USERS_KEY_PIN + " = '" + pin + "'" , null);

         ........
    }
```

Then in the activity class, I'm calling

```
UserDataSource uds = new UserDataSource (this);
uds.OpenWriteable();
uds.ValidateLogin("name", "pin");
```

Any help would be great, thanks very much
Graham

The following is the attached log from the error report

```
11-23 17:47:46.414: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(26717): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: Users, db=/data/data/prometric.myitemwriter/databases/MyUser.db
11-23 17:47:57.085: D/AndroidRuntime(26717): Shutting down VM
11-23 17:47:57.085: W/dalvikvm(26717): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40bec1f8)
11-23 17:47:57.171: D/dalvikvm(26717): GC_CONCURRENT freed 575K, 8% free 8649K/9351K, paused 2ms+6ms
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3091)
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3558)
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14152)
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3086)
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717):    ... 11 more
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Users: , while compiling: select * from Users where email = '' and pin = ''
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:127)
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:94)
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:53)
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1685)
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1659)
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717):    at projectname.database.UserDataSource.ValidateLogin(UserDataSource.java:73)
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717):    at projectname.LoginActivity.btn_login_Click(LoginActivity.java:47)
11-23 17:47:57.179: E/AndroidRuntime(26717):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: please share the error logs also

Comment: Hey Ahmed, thanks for the response. I've tried what you suggested by changing 'UserDataSource uds = new UserDataSource(this)' to ''UserDataSource uds = new UserDataSource(LoginActivity.this)'; but it still did not work.

Arun Antony. I'll post up the error logs now, thank you

Comment: I have attached the error report to the question

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks for the help. The reason why this was not working was because the database inserts were not being committed. The following is how I got around the issue if anyone is interested.

```
// Create the Users table
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    Log.d(DatabaseHandler.class.getName(), "Creating table " + TABLE_USERS);
    String CREATE_USERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_USERS + "("
            + KEY_PRIMARY_ID + " " + INTEGER + " " + PRIMARY_KEY + ","
            + USERS_KEY_EMAIL + " " + NVARCHAR+"(1000)" + " " + UNIQUE + " " + NOT_NULL + ","
            + USERS_KEY_PIN + " " + NVARCHAR+"(10)" + " " + NOT_NULL + ");"; 
    db.execSQL(CREATE_USERS_TABLE);
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    Log.e(DatabaseHandler.class.getName(), "Error Creating table " + TABLE_USERS + " ... " + e.getMessage());
    // Do whatever you want here
}
finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't show all of your variables, but I am guessing that something is wrong with the `CREATE_USERS_TABLE` statement. Let's organize and simplify it:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users(" +
    KEY_PRIMARY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + 
    USERS_KEY_EMAIL + " NVARCHAR(1000) UNIQUE NOT NULL, " + 
    USERS_KEY_PIN + " NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL)";
```

You will need to tell the database that the SQL schema needs to be updated by changing `DATABASE_VERSION` to `2`.

---

Also you should protect yourself from SQL injection attacks by using the `selectionArgs` parameter in your queries:

```
public void ValidateLogin(String username, String pin) throws CustomException
{   
     Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(   "select * from Users where " + DatabaseHandler.USERS_KEY_EMAIL + " = ? and " + DatabaseHandler.USERS_KEY_PIN + " = ?", 
             new String[] {username, pin});
```

---

Lastly you should observe Java naming convention and start all of your methods with a lowercase letter: `openWritable()`, `close(),`validateLogin()`, etc.

Comment: Sam I have tried to change the database version number but still no joy, i've also uninstalled the application and installed it onto my device and same. 

Thanks for the top about he SQL injection, I have made your suggested changes, thank you very much.

Comment: Cut & paste your logcat errors into your question, so we can see exactly what is happening.

Comment: Did you change `CREATE_USERS_TABLE` to the code above before incrementing the database version?

Comment: Sam thanks so much, that seemed to do the job. It seems to be letting me into the database now. Thank you so much for your response, really appreciate your help

Comment: Hi @Sam, sorry for reopening this discussion. I'm having the exact same problem again. I must be doing something wrong. In the constructor of the DatabaseHandler class, I'm just calling a function that will tell me whether or not I can open the database and it returns true. Then when the onCreate method is called, my method call returns false saying that the database is locked. Do you know why this database would be locked => tables don't seem to be getting created?

Comment: Since you have changed the code and are receiving a new set of errors, should should open a new question. Leave a link here in our comments here pointing to the new question so I know when it's posted.

Answer (score 0):

Change your 
`protected static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;` 
to 
`protected static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;` 
It will resolve the Exception.

Comment: Hi, thanks I've tried this but it still fails to work. I must be doing something wrong. Just for debugging purposes, in the constructor of the DatabaseHandler class, I'm just calling a function that will tell me whether or not I can open the database and it returns true. Then when the onCreate method is called, my function call returns false saying that the database is locked. Do you know why this database would be locked => tables don't seem to be getting created. Can you see what might be wrong

Comment: In UserDataSource class you are trying to select the data after Closing the database. that is after writing the database_close() method. So after closing the database itself you are trying to select the data. I think thats the reason of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In `UserDataSource` class you are trying to select the data after Closing the database. That is after writing the `database_close()` method. So after closing the database itself you are trying to select the data. I think that's the reason of the issue. And consider updating the `database_version` even in `UserDataSource` class. Try both of these things. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Priety, it still doesn't seem to be working. I've also tried to add in some seed data just to go in at the beginning, and just can't seem to be getting it to work. I'd say it could be just something small, but I'd say it's something fundamental in the way in which I'm trying to connect to the database :-(

Answer (score 0):

In this method:

```
public void ValidateLogin(String username, String pin) throws CustomException
{   
     Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from Users where " +
     DatabaseHandler.USERS_KEY_EMAIL + " = '" + username + "'" + " and " +
     DatabaseHandler.USERS_KEY_PIN + " = '" + pin + "'" , null);
     ........
}
```

replace code by

```
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from Users where"
 +DatabaseHandler.USERS_KEY_EMAIL+"='"+username+"'"+"and"+ 
 DatabaseHandler.USERS_KEY_PIN +"='"+pin+"'", null);
```

I think that extra space is mattering. Please try it. I hope it works.
Let me know if you got the solution.